# iOS Google Map View ruins my design

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a full screen map in my iOS app implemented with Google Map iOS SDK. There is sliding menu panel, that slides from bottom. It is just a UIView with buttons. It works ok until i start to interact with Map. When a move camera - my expanded menu View becomes invisible. So i need to tap menu button again to collapse it and tap another one to expand it again. Is there any way to make UIView always on top of views stack?

code for expanding and collapsing menu:

```
@IBAction func menuButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let animation = { () -> Void in
            self.bottomMenu.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height -
                self.bottomMenu.frame.size.height
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: animation)
    }

@IBAction func dropDownMenuButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let animation = { () -> Void in
            self.bottomMenu.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: animation)
    }
```

Comment: try "bringSubviewToFront" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the MapView on the storyboard then all view are put in the back for some reason.

```
mapView = new MapView(View.Bounds);
Background.InsertSubview(mapView, 0);
```

So if you add the MapView this way, then your views are kept in front of the map. The only problem is that you will have to handle device orientation framing.